# Display woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart() outside of loop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display the add to cart button and variables dropdown / price inside a custom theme, built on Genesis.

I have created some code so that if the product is a simple product, it displays a custom form with the add to cart/quantity buttons inside the header (in functions.php > is_product()).

This works fine. What I'm now trying to do is display a similar form if it's a variable product, but obviously display the variable product dropdowns and add to cart/price, etc as they would default show in Woocommerce, but displaying it in the header, outside the loop.

I have this code:

```
$product_id = get_the_id();
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

<?php
  if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ):
    $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
    $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
    $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
    $html .= '</form>';
    echo $html;

elseif ($product->is_type('variable'))  : 
    woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart();
endif; ?>
```

I think `woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart()` should display the add to cart template for variables out of the box, but I'm getting an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_children() on string in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php on line 1733
```

Do I need to pass $product into it somehow?